# Identifying confusing value targets in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is a question involving Python, [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), and HTML, as well as the [Investopedia API](https://github.com/kirkthaker/investopedia-trading-api).

The first part involved is this block of Python that takes an input and executes a function based off of the given input (action is `raw_input`):

```
if action == 'trade':
    symbol = raw_input("Symbol: ")
    order_type = raw_input("Order Type: ")
    quantity = raw_input("Quantity: ")

    if order_type == 'buy':
        client.trade(str(symbol), ita.Action.buy, int(quantity))
    elif order_type == 'sell':
        client.trade(str(symbol), ita.Action.sell, int(quantity))
    elif order_type == 'short':
        client.trade(str(symbol), ita.Action.short, int(quantity))
```

The second parameter (`ita.Action.[order_type]`), written as directed in the API documentation, and as indicated in the code itself, refers to this block:

```
# input transaction type
[option.attrs.pop("selected", "") for option in trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0]("option")]
trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0].find("option", {"value": str(orderType.value)})["selected"] = True
```

That block uses `.find` from Beautiful Soup to target a drop-down menu that is formatted as such:

```
<select name="transactionTypeDropDown" id="transactionTypeDropDown" style="width: auto;">
        <option value="1">Buy</option>
        <option value="2">Sell</option>
        <option value="3">Sell Short</option>
        <option value="4">Buy to Cover</option>
</select>
```

In the API's documentation, the examples are listed to operate as follows:

```
client.trade("GOOG", ita.Action.buy, 10)
```

However, `AttributeError` is reporting that `'int' object has no attribute 'value'`, in that given line, even when I've attempted to run the line as it is written in the documentation on its own.

```
File "/fakepath/MMIAS/ita/ita.py", line 233, in trade
    trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0].find("option", {"value": str(orderType.value)})["selected"] = True
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I am assuming that the `int` object in question is the `option` value from the drop-down menu, and with that, I am assuming that that an `int`, perhaps 1 - 4, is occupying the `orderType` parameter. So, why would it be suggested that the parameter be `ita.Action.[buy/sell/short/etc]`, rather than just an integer value? And why does it return the same error if an integer value fulfills that parameter? Help me understand.

Comment: Running just `client.trade("GOOG", ita.Action.buy, 10)` is not working? This line of code works for me, and it should work for you too, try reinstalling the library or double checking the versions.

Comment: I'll try it again but I've been running tests and they've never worked out. Reinstalling might help.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar , in what context did that operation work? I'm wondering if I am missing some small mistake.

Comment: I installed the library, and then, as the docs said: `from InvestopediaApi import ita` and then `client = ita.Account("emailaddress", "password")` (I have an account, I used it), and finally `client.trade("GOOG", ita.Action.buy, 10)` returned `True`, working fine. I'm using Python3.6 and installed the library with `python3.6 -m pip install InvestopediaApi`.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using python 2.7?

Comment: It might be, I'm not sure either.