# Interpreter integration failure with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This question refers to a [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809967/identifying-confusing-value-targets-in-beautiful-soup#comment78611297_45809967).

I had been using the [Investopedia API](https://github.com/kirkthaker/investopedia-trading-api), which uses [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to interact with the Investopedia Trading Simulator. My initial problem was the report of `AttributeError`, but that report no longer seems to matter (if you wish for more details of the original problem, see below).

After a suggestion, I installed Python 3.6, as I was previously using 2.7, and ran my tests again. That time, the operation worked correctly. But, I don't know the reason why. Why would, if the API is built to operate with both p2.7 and p3.6, the functions work in 3.6? Does it have to do with Beautiful Soup integration? Or perhaps `input` vs `raw_input`?

## Prerequisite Details

The first part involved is this block of Python that takes an input and executes a function based off of the given input (action is `raw_input`):

```
if action == 'trade':
    symbol = raw_input("Symbol: ")
    order_type = raw_input("Order Type: ")
    quantity = raw_input("Quantity: ")

    if order_type == 'buy':
        client.trade(str(symbol), ita.Action.buy, int(quantity))
    elif order_type == 'sell':
        client.trade(str(symbol), ita.Action.sell, int(quantity))
    elif order_type == 'short':
        client.trade(str(symbol), ita.Action.short, int(quantity))
```

The second parameter (`ita.Action.[order_type]`), written as directed in the API documentation, and as indicated in the code itself, refers to this block:

```
# input transaction type
[option.attrs.pop("selected", "") for option in trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0]("option")]
trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0].find("option", {"value": str(orderType.value)})["selected"] = True
```

That block uses `.find` from Beautiful Soup to target a drop-down menu that is formatted as such:

```
<select name="transactionTypeDropDown" id="transactionTypeDropDown" style="width: auto;">
        <option value="1">Buy</option>
        <option value="2">Sell</option>
        <option value="3">Sell Short</option>
        <option value="4">Buy to Cover</option>
</select>
```

In the API's documentation, the examples are listed to operate as follows:

```
client.trade("GOOG", ita.Action.buy, 10)
```

However, `AttributeError` is reporting that `'int' object has no attribute 'value'`, in that given line, even when I've attempted to run the line as it is written in the documentation on its own.

```
File "/fakepath/MMIAS/ita/ita.py", line 233, in trade
    trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0].find("option", {"value": str(orderType.value)})["selected"] = True
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I am assuming that the `'int'` object in question is the `option` value from the drop-down menu, and with that, I am assuming that that an `int`, perhaps 1 - 4, is occupying the `orderType` parameter. So, why would it be suggested that the parameter be `ita.Action.[buy/sell/short/etc]`, rather than just an integer value? And why does it return the same error if an integer value fulfills that parameter?

Comment: Add the related code to **this** question.

Comment: @KlausD. - done.